# NFS server generating "invalid extent" on EXT4 system disk?

Tags: server, apt, ext4, nfs

I have a server running Xen 4.1 with Oneiric in the dom0 and each of the 4 domUs. The system disks of the domUs are LVM2 volumes built on top of an mdadm RAID1.

All the domU system disks are EXT4 and are created using snapshots of the same original template. 3 of them run perfectly, but one (called s-ub-02) keeps on being remounted read-only. A subsequent `e2fsck` results in a single "invalid extent" diagnosis:

```
e2fsck 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
/dev/domu/s-ub-02-root contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 525418 has an invalid extent
    (logical block 8959, invalid physical block 0, len 0)
Clear<y>? yes

Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/domu/s-ub-02-root: 77757/655360 files (0.3% non-contiguous), 360592/2621440 blocks
```

The console shows typically the following errors for the system disk (xvda2):

```
[101980.903416] EXT4-fs error (device xvda2): ext4_ext_find_extent:732: inode #525418: comm apt-get: bad header/extent: invalid extent entries - magic f30a, entries 12, max 340(340), depth 0(0)
[101980.903473] EXT4-fs (xvda2): Remounting filesystem read-only
```

I have created new versions of the system disk. The same thing always happens. This, and the fact that the disk is ultimately on a RAID1, leads me to preclude a hardware disk error.

The only obvious distinguishing feature of this domU is the presence of `nfs-kernel-server`, so I suspect that. Its `exports` file looks like this:

```
/exports/users           192.168.0.0/255.255.248.0(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
/exports/media/music     192.168.0.0/255.255.248.0(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
/exports/media/pictures  192.168.0.0/255.255.248.0(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
/exports/opt             192.168.0.0/255.255.248.0(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

`/exports/users` and `/exports/opt` are LVM2 volumes from the same volume group as the system disk. `/exports/media` is an EXT2 volume. (There is an issue where clients see `/exports/media/pictures` as being a read-only volume, which I mention for completeness.)

With the exception of the read-only problem, the NFS server appears to work correctly under light load for several hours before the "invalid extent" problem occurs.

There are no helpful entries in `/var/log`. All of a sudden, no more files are written, so you can see when the disk was remounted read-only, but there is no indication of what the cause might be.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Steve

Comment: I'm unclear as to what domain is managing what devices.  Do you mean that dom0 is running mdadm on top of the real disks, or that the dumUs are running mdadm on top of virtual disks?

Comment: The dom0 is running mdadm (a simple RAID1 with 2 465GB disks) as /dev/md0. LVM2 on the dom0 uses /dev/md0 as a physical volume to create a volume group called "domu". The system disks are created in domu and passed to the domUs as /dev/xvdaN, etc.

Comment: I've taken a closer look at the inodes that have been reported as having invalid extents. They correspond to  /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin,
/var/lib/dpkg/info/nfs-kernel-server.list,
/var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin, and
/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-security_universe_source_Sources. Looks like it might be an apt-related problem. But apt is not causing any problems on the other domUs...

Comment: You aren't passing the same LV to multiple domUs are you?

Comment: No, I'm not. Though I did try it once. It would be cool if you could do that with read-only partitions. But I digress.

Comment: It is looking increasingly as though the problem has something to do with APT, though I don't understand why it should have happened here and not in the other domUs. Nor do I understand why it should have happened  in several different instantiations of the same domU. Everything points to NFS, but the problem is APT? Could it be that there is something wrong with the packaging of nfs-kernel-server? I've started using apt-cacher-ng, did an apt-get update and now have over 38 hours uptime, which is a record for that domU ;-)

Comment: I thought you were passing LVs to the domUs to use as virtual disks.  Where does NFS fit into the picture?

Comment: @psusi The domUs have specific functions: 1) database server; 2) user file server ("cloud"); 3) web server; 4) development tools. Each has a system disk, cloned from a template with common functionality, and one or more other disks. The cloud provides each user with file storage which is accessible through WebDAV outside of the firewall and NFS within the LAN. Clients within the LAN use NFS to access the cloud. However, the problem child - the cloud - has now been running without problems for 4+ days. I think the problem is solved. I don't know why but could write an answer with my guesses.

Comment: I finally solved this problem by ditching ext4 and going back to ext3 after ext4 started playing up again. There's something weird going on in that particular VM, but I can't spend any more time on trying to find out what it is.

Answer (score 2):

This problem was solved by the OP:

> I finally solved this problem by ditching ext4 and going back to ext3
>   after ext4 started playing up again. There's something weird going on
>   in that particular VM, but I can't spend any more time on trying to
>   find out what it is.